# Vue.js priority watchers not working on form submission

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, input, watch

My page is displaying user data, which he can edit.
I'm working with views, on a small project. I want to do form validation with regex, but nothing happens. Exemple, When I write an email that does not respect the syntax of a regex no message is displayed.
When the regex is valid the validation message also does not appear.

```js
export default {
  name: "profile",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {},
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      email: "",
      msg: [],
    };
  },
  watch: {
    email() {
      this.validateEmail(this.email);
    },
  },

  methods: {
    getProfilUser() {
      UsersDataService.getUser()
        .then((response) => {
          let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
          let decoded = VueJwtDecode.decode(token);
          this.user = decoded;
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error, "error from decoding token");
        });
    },
    validateEmail(email) {
      if (/^[\w-.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/.test(email)) {
        this.msg["email"] = "Email valid";
      } else {
        this.msg["email"] = "Adress no valid";
      }
    },
   
   
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getProfilUser();
    this.email;
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
   <form class="background-style">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-label">Prénom</label>
                        <input
                          id="firstname"
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="user.firstname"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-label">Nom</label>
                        <input
                          id="lastname"
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="user.lastname"
                        />
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>

                        <input
                          id="email"
                          type="email"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="user.email"
                        />
                        <span v-if="msg.email">{{ msg.email }}</span>
                      </div>

                      <div class="btn rounded p-1">
                      

                        <button
                          type="button"
                          class="rounded p-2"
                          @click.prevent="updateProfil"
                        >
                         register
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two email property email and user.email.You are watching only email. but binding user.email in v-modal. so watchers will not call. you can console.log in watchers to check that

solutions:

```
    watch: {
      'user.email'(newVal){
          this.validateEmail(newVal);
       }
   }
```

And the other thing is don't use 'this.email' or 'this.user.email' directly on watchers. instead, use newVal as shown in this code. Vue js update all data properly asynchronously so which is not guaranteed for updated value so always use newVal for that.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about 2-way binding.

First, you should pass `v-model` to your inputs like this. Don't pass `value`, `v-model` will do it for you.

```
<input
  v-model="email"
  type="email"
  class="form-control"
/>
```

Second, don't mutate email inside watcher - you'll get into the loop.
Just call `validateEmail` method.

```
watch: {
  email() {
    this.validateEmail(this.email);
  },
},
```

That should work then.

Comment: Thank you, I will make the changes in my code.

Comment: For the v-model directive, I have to write user.firstname. It is a precise object that I recover because, in this object there are the three fields mentioned.

Comment: Nothing is taken into account when I enter a wrong or correct address.

Comment: I updated and shared my code, but nothing happened.